# My recursive program to find the smallest value in an array is not working

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I have created a program which finds the minimum value in an array using recursion but it is not working how I intended. I don't know why but it is not returning the actual lowest value in my output. Here is my code:

```
package weekFour;

public class MinInt {

    static int[] arr = {24,52,74,9,34,23,64,34};
    static int min;
    static int minIndex;

    public static void main(String[] args){
    MinInt m = new MinInt();
    System.out.println("Minimum is :" + m.findMin(arr, 0, min));
    }

    public int findMin(int[] arr, int index, int min){
        if(index <= (arr.length - 1)){    //makes sure you only check elements in the array
            if(arr[index] < min){        //if value is smaller than current min
                min = arr[index];        //set new min
                minIndex = index;        //records position of min in array
            }
            return findMin(arr, index + 1, min);   //recursive method call
        }
        System.out.println("The Minimum Value in this Array is " + min + " at Index " + minIndex);
        return min;
    }
}
```

My output is:

```
The Minimum Value in this Array is 0 at Index 0
Minimum is :0
```

Comment: You start with an initial `min` of `0`.  How do you expect anything in your array to be smaller than that?  Set your starting min value to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: Provide the min as the first element of your array. In your case min value is 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change min value in your code and here is very optimised code to do this reverse job

```
int mini(int array[], int size) {
    if (size == 1) {
        return array[0];
    }
    else {
        return (array[size] < mini(array, size - 1)) ? array[size]: mini(array, size - 1);
    }
}
```

Hope my help works happy coding.

Comment: You either need to change it to `if (size == 0)` or call `array[size-1]`, otherwise you will either get an index out of bounds error or an incorrect result. Also, this is very inefficient because you can just store the value of `mini(array, size-1)` in a variable instead of calling it twice in the `return` statement. e.g. `int x = mini(array, size-1); return (array[size] < x) ? array[size] : x;`

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way to fix it without changing the whole code is to start your min at the first value of your array when you called findMin in the main.

```
System.out.println("Minimum is :" + m.findMin(arr, 0, arr[0]));
```

instead of

```
System.out.println("Minimum is :" + m.findMin(arr, 0, min));
```